# GetFeatureInfo for gxp_olsource in OGS GeoExplorer

Tags: getfeatureinfo, geoexplorer

We have an OpenGeo Suite GeoExplorer 3.0.1 and want to make GetFeatureInfo-requests, via the identify button, for WMS-layers of type gxp_olsource but it doesn't work, I get no response at all and I don't get any errors in the browser debug console. It works great to make a GetFeatureInfo-request for WMS-layers with sources of type gxp_wmscsource
or gxp_wmssource.

Is it supposed to be working in the original version of GeoExplorer or do I have to make adjustments to the code?

Layer configuration:

```
...
sources: {
...
           ol: { ptype: "gx_olsource" }
},
map: {
...
        { group: "groupfisketsgeografier", 
        visibility: false, 
        queryable: true,
        source: "ol",
        type: "OpenLayers.Layer.WMS",
        args: ["Fredningsomraden", 
            "http://geodata.havochvatten.se/geoservices/hav-fisketsgeografier/ows",
            { layers: "hav-fisketsgeografier:havet-fredningsomraden",    
            transparent: true, 
            isBaseLayer: false,
            tiled: true} ]
            },

        }
...
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue, though I can do get feature info for some features but not all! Really strange and hopeless to debug.

Comment: do you have a proxy setup? assuming these layers are on a different machine than your GeoExplorer you will need a proxy

Answer (score 1):

gx_olsource (implemented by OLSource.js) doesnt read the queryable attribute in getCapabilities.

But after this commit to gxp: https://github.com/bartvde/gxp/commit/1a492e6250c71843c24b0d0804bfe011311c42ff you can add queryable:true/false to the configuration of a layer on the same level as group.

E.g.https://gist.github.com/emoen/11249020

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with gx_olsource. Im on geoexplorer 2.4.3 so had to add some code to get this working. Code can be viewer here: https://github.com/Norwegian-marine-datacentre/mareano/blob/master/src/main/webapp/javascript/mareano_common.js#L113